# Want the website to wait for until Youtube embedded gets fetched

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, iframe

I have a react app where I want to showcase many youtube videos, what I did was to create an array of youtube embed links and map them inside a div. Now the problem is, they load very slowly Is there any way we can load them faster? or can we check something like "areVideosFetched" if it returns true only show otherwise show a lottie(or maybe just show the thumbnail of the video).

This is how i am currently displaying the videos:

```
<div className={styles.col} id="reel-block">
   <div className={styles.reelsContainer}>
      {youtubeShortsUrlList.map((short, key) => (
        <Reels
          key={i}
          url={list.url}
           isMobileView={false}
        />
   </div>
</div>
```

and this is the reels component:

```
const reelRef = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
        const scroll = document.getElementById("reel-block");
        if (scroll) {
            scroll.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
                reelRef.current.contentWindow.postMessage(
                    '{"event":"command", "func":"stopVideo", "args":""}',
                    "*",
                );
            });
        }
    }, []);
    return (
        <div className={styles.videoReel}>
            <iframe
                ref={reelRef}
                id={props.url}
                loading="lazy"
                className={`${
                    props.isMobileView
                        ? styles.playerMobile
                        : styles.videoPlayer
                }`}
                src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${props.url}?autplay=1&loop=1&controls=1&&enablejsapi=1&disablekb=1&&playsinline=1&color=red&showinfo=0&modestbranding=1&rel=0`}
                allow="accelerometer;clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
            ></iframe>
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: Could you show us an example of how you are loading them - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - it sounds like you need to show thumbnail of a video until it is loaded and you don't want to wait for all of them to be loaded (maybe load on user clicking?) but we can't tell from what you've told us so far.

Comment: @AHaworth my apologies i was not clear with my problem here is how i am currently loading the videos: https://pastebin.pl/view/b342a7b0

Comment: @AHaworth what you said was correct i want to show thumbnail and only on click but that is later on for now i want is to play the next video when i scroll it into view 
i made another post you check it it would give you more clarity
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74764728/stop-previous-video-and-play-next-video-on-scroll

Comment: Please put the code into your actual question, not another site.

Comment: @AHaworth i have made the changes can you check please